# Ruby on Rails: Can't View Assets from Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Executive Summary (3 HOURS of incorrect guesses made)

- All I am trying to do is add a new picture that I can access from my browser.
- I have tried the following things: 1) Put new jpg (header2.jpg) in assets folder (rake assets:clean rake assets:precompile) AND in the app/public folder.

I test the accessibility of the new file by pointing my browser to either http://localhost:3000/assets/header2.jpg or http://localhost:3000/header2.jpg

Here is proof that the file actually exists.

```
ls -l public/header2.jpeg 
-rw-r-----@ 1 vic  staff  7181148 Dec 25 10:47 public/header2.jpeg

ls -l app/assets/images/header2.jpeg 
-rw-r-----@ 1 vic  staff  7181148 Dec 25 10:47 app/assets/images/header2.jpeg
```

This is the error that I get. It is a routing error, which means the file is unaccessible and it goes to the 'routing' phase within Rails (as many have explained on this site).

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/header2.jpg"):
```

Here are the things that I have tried.

1. Read the Assets Pipeline Documentation provided.
2. Added the following to both my config/environment/production.rb and config/environment/development.rb

   config.serve_static_assets = true
3. Ran rake assets:clean and rake assets:precompile (100x times)
4. Restarted my Server (rails s)
5. Watched Ryan Bates Asset Pipeline Video.

This site is designed to be deployed on Heroku BUT all the errors I am talking about are on my local rails instance.

My gut says there is some sort of configuration error as placing files in the assets or public folder and running rake clean and rake pre-compile should fix this.

Here is what is REALLY interesting.

I can access this through my browser.
http://localhost:3000/assets/header2-b1088c11bf403f9b3358fbed3d4b54f1.jpeg
(Which is located in the public/assets/images subfolder)
BUT I can't access just the header2.jpg which is located in the EXACT same folder!

Please Help friends

Comment: There's no need to do asset precompile in local.

Comment: FOUND the answer. Rails gets confused if you put both a file in the app/assets folder and the public folder.  Use one or the other. In this case i removed the file from the assets folder and just placed it in the public folder.

Comment: i don't recommend to put assets in the public in the development mode.
only assets/public is only used for serving to production(which is assets precompiling)